# New MacBook Pro with 308GB used disk space

Tags: macos, mac

I just got the new 15inch MacBook Pro with 512GB SSD. After running `df -h`, here's the output:

`Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     465Gi  308Gi  157Gi    67% 80721356 41118258   66%   /`

Disk Inventory X only shows my Macintosh HD to be using 44.9GB of space. What's going on here?

Comment: Well seeing as how I was just about to suggest running Disk Inv X (WinDirStat) I'm going to go ahead and say that it's accurate. 44.9GB seems more suitable for a new OSX installation as opposed to 308GB used on default (WTF?! indeed) Is this computer OEM new? or new from a 3rd party? I suggest looking into cache's, `pagefile` (or w/e it is for Mac), and/or rogue files/installations seeing as these have always been the culprit in my past experiences.

Comment: First guess would be local caching for Time Machine, if you have that switched on

Comment: I just ran `df -h` again (after many other tries yesterday), and now it's good... Sitting at 45Gi used and 420Gi available. So I'm just puzzled at this glitch. I didn't install anything and didn't even restart the machine. Time Machine is Off. I just got the machine delivered to my house so it should be OEM new. But thanks guys for the help!